# Theories of Human Motivation

Tags: motivation

I have heard the true saying that without motivation, there will be no action on anything which needs to be done. I can't remember where I heard it but I have wondered about what help there can be to remove motivational barriers.

I know of [Maslow's Hierarchy of Needs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maslow%27s_hierarchy_of_needs) and then I came across Szondi's [Drive Diagnostic Test](http://www.szondiforum.org/t419.htm) which made me wonder. What other theories and methods are out there?

Comment: Have you tried [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_theory)?  Long list there...

Comment: I hadn't heard of "content theory" so that was helpful @ArnonWeinberg. Thanks